# Cloud firestore data not updating after adding data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update a document on cloud firestore after adding some data to the document. I am following these steps:

1. Add data to firestore document and get document id
2. Upload some file to firebase storage with that document id as file name
3. Get download link from storage and update the download link in firestore with the retrieved download link

Relevant part of my code is here;

```
firestore.collection("words").doc(word).collection("data").add({
        link: ""
    }).then(function(docRef) {
        let filepath = // some path;
            storage.ref(filepath).put(FILE).then(function(snapshot) {
            console.log("Uploading Files");
            storage.ref(filepath).getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
                 firestore.collection("words").doc(word).collection("data").ref(docRef.id).update({
                    link: downloadURL
                }).then(function() {
                    // THIS PART ISN'T EXECUTING AT ALL
                    // NO CONOSLE LOG AND NO ERRORS PRINTED
                    console.log("Updated downlaod link");
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error Updating Link");
                    console.log(error);
                })
            })
        })
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
```

The problem is, the update part is not working at all. Other parts work as intended but the update part is not executing at all (console.log() inside the update doesn't print anything). Even no error is reported in the console.

What is the problem here? How can I make it work?

Comment: Have you checked if anything before the update call triggers an error (e.g. getDownloadURL())?

Comment: I did. Everything before the update call triggers. The downloadURL is also successfully retrieved. Execution stops just before the update part